# Karma browsers always timing out

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I have installed karma in my project's folder (tried both globally and locally). I have one source file all_source_minified.js and one test called sample_test.js, they are both loaded like shown below. I also exported CHROME_BIN.

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'all_source_minified.js',
  'sample_test.js'
],
browsers: ['Chrome'],
captureTimeout : 30000,
```

When I issue command `karma start`, it says `Starting browser Chrome`, Chromium opens up but it says "webpage not available". After 30s it times out and tries again, but without success.

When I try with PhantomJS, it simply times out after 30s.

How to debug this issue? I just cannot get it to start..

Comment: I have never tried any of those, but try to wrap your code inside `{[...]}` and hope for the best. And remove the last coma on `captureTimeout`.

Comment: can you post your whole config?
Also, did you set a port?

Comment: The whole config http://pastebin.com/AEVc3epf but it's very bare bones